How to add line breaks to Instagram Reels Description with Instagram Graph API call?
We developed our own platform to schedule Instagram Posts via the Instagram Graph API.
It's working fine but we can't find a way to add linebreaks to the Reel Description.
We tried to use \n as well as some html tags like <p> but nothing works. It's like after publication, Instagram automatically deletes the spaces and reduces them to one space.
I know it's possible because some scheduling SAAS like Later can schedule Reels with linebreaks in the description.
I'm trying to find someone who solved the problem already.
What should I try next? How to format the json?
Thanks,
T.

The description is supposed to be plain text, and can't contain HTML, as far as I know. So \n is really about the only thing that could make sense, I suppose. But they might perhaps suppress it, because it gets misused too much for spammy purposes.

Maybe you can check some more unicode newline symbols. The \n will not work as @CBroe already said, but there are some more. I had no possibility to check these. Check here for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Unicode Additionally you can check the HTML that is returned if reel is posted by later. If you discover the character I'm interested, too :D
